# Предупреждение с неинициализированным значением

Tags: c++, c

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять почему я получаю предупреждение:

```
1 errors in context 1 of 1:
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in...)
```

Сам код:

```
size_t getLine(char** line, size_t *capacity, FILE *stream)
{
    if (*capacity == 0)
    {
        // initial capacity
        *capacity = 32;
    }

    if (*line == NULL)
    {
        *line = malloc(*capacity * sizeof(char));
        if (*line == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // number of chars actually in *line
    size_t n = 0;

    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        if ((n + 1) > *capacity)
        {
            if (*capacity <= (SIZE_MAX / 2))
            {
                *capacity *= 2;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }

            char *temp = realloc(*line, *capacity * sizeof(char));
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                *capacity = n;
                return 0;
            }
            *line = temp;
        }
        (*line)[n++] = (char)c;
    }
    return n;
}
```

```
int main()
{

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t capacity = 2;

    size_t n = getLine(&line, &capacity, stdin);

    printf("Line: %s\nCapacity: %zu\nn = %zu\n", line, capacity, n);

    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

```
==5463== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5463==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5463==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,062 bytes allocated
==5463== 
==5463== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5463== 
==5463== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5463== 
==5463== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==5463== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5463==    at 0x4C32D08: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5463==    by 0x4E994D2: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1643)
==5463==    by 0x4EA0F25: printf (printf.c:33)
==5463==    by 0x1089AD: main (in /home/vlad/vlad/c-projects/database/main)
==5463==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5463==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5463==    by 0x1088D7: getLine (in /home/vlad/vlad/c-projects/database/main)
==5463==    by 0x108989: main (in /home/vlad/vlad/c-projects/database/main)
==5463== 
==5463== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Функция читает строку из потока, не очищая память в случае неудачи.

Comment: Так а о каком именно `realloc` идет речь в сообщении?

Comment: @AnT Я предоставил код. Других `realloc'ов` у меня нет.

Comment: `realloc` может быть в стандартных функциях. В сообщении было ясно указано, о каком `realloc` идет речь: имя файла и строка. Вы целиком сообщение не привели. Там стояла ссылка именно на ваш `realloc`?

Comment: @AnT `at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)` вот эта ссылка была.

Comment: Ну а дальше? Там должно быть `by`, `by`, `by`...

Comment: @AnT `by 0x1088D7: getLine (in /home/vlad/vlad/c-projects/database/main)
by 0x108992: main (in /home/vlad/vlad/c-projects/database/main)`

Comment: Так а какой именно jump? У вас в сообщении должно было быть сказано точно таким же образом, о каком именно jump идет речь.

Comment: @AnT Я отредактировал пост, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Может быть ваш компайлер не понимает `%zu` в **printf** => попробуйте `%ld`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe попробовал, но все та же ошибка. И с `%zu` все работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в "строке" нет замыкающего нулевого терминатора. Неудивительно, что попытка печати такой "строки" через `printf` вылетает в неинициализированную память.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Я очень невнимательный.

Answer (score 0):

Почему в функции getLine используешь двойной указатель на строку?

```
(char** line)
```

так не проще?

```
size_t getLine(char * line, size_t *capacity, FILE *stream)
```

Comment: нет, так работать не будет, если `NULL` передавать.

Comment: к тому же, еще будут утечки памяти возникать